# In BeautifulSoup4, Python3, How to stop recursing inside a found tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My html document looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
 <font color="#151B54">
     outer font
   <font color="#512222">
       inner font
   </font>
 </font>
 <p>
     <font color="#512222">
       sibling font
     </font>
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to extract all the text between the 'font' tags. Expected Output:

```
outer font
inner font
sibling font
```

What I have tried is:

1. using text

   ```
   soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText)
   for i in soup.body.find_all('font'):
       print(i.text)
   ```

   gives me repitions:

   ```
   outer font
   inner font
   inner font
   sibling font
   ```
2. using string

   ```
   soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText)
   for i in soup.body.find_all('font')
       print(i.string)
   ```

   misses some text:

   ```
   None
   inner font
   sibling font
   ```

How can I get the desired output?

**Update**

The html document is only an example I have given to explain the situation. In some documents I have, it is not necessary that the 'font' tag containing 'sibling font' will always be inside a 'p' tag. There can also be multiple 'font' tags nested inside various other tags. So, I need a generic solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the parent is not also a `font` tag.

```
print([node.text for node in soup.find_all('font') if node.parent.name != "font"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for node in soup.findAll('font'):    
    inner_text = [element for element in node if isinstance(element, NavigableString)]
    print (''.join(inner_text))

outer font  
inner font 
sibling font
```